# How to get user ID in libraries CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to get user ID in libraries,

User Table

| ID | username |
|---------------|
| 1  | Alex     |
| 2  | Johey    |
| 3  | Leos     |
| 4  | Pacat    |

Store Table

```
| ID | userID | store_picture |
|-----------------------------|
| 1  | Alex   | img1.jpg      |
| 2  | Johey  | img3.jpg      |
| 3  | Leos   | img2.jpg      |
| 4  | Pacat  | img5.jpg      |
```

libraries/Store.php

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Store 
{

    var $info=array();

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $site = $CI->db->select("userID,store_background")
        ->where("userID", 3)
        ->get("store_info");

        if($site->num_rows() == 0) {
            $CI->template->error(
                "You are missing the site settings database row."
            );
        } else {
            $this->info = $site->row();
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use get_instance() instead:

```
//Model name : Store_info_model.php
function get_userID( $id ) {
    $this->db->select( 'userID, store_background' );
    $this->db->where( 'userID', $id );
    return $this->db->get( 'store_info' );
}
```

Library

```
<?php
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
    class Store { 
        public $info=array(); 
        public function __construct() { 
            $CI =& get_instance(); 
            $CI->load->model( 'Store_info_model' );
            $site = $CI->Store_info_model->get_userID( 3 );
            if($site->num_rows() == 0) { 
                //Do something when error happen
            } 
            else $this->info = $site->row();  
        } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: can you give example in this code,
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 

class Store 
{

    var $info=array();

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $site = $CI->db->select("userID,store_background")
        ->where("userID", 3)
        ->get("store_info");

        if($site->num_rows() == 0) {
            $CI->template->error(
                "You are missing the site settings database row."
            );
        } else {
            $this->info = $site->row();
        }
    }

}

?>

Answer (score 0):

TRy to load Database in your library or add in auto load in config

add this in ur library

```
$this->load->database();
```